# Physical Review page split

Tags: spacing

The physical review preprint template splits the page into two columns for a journal style. I have both long equations and large figures which I would like to display on a full line.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Assuming you are using `revtex4-1` or `revtex4-2`: two-column figures are obtained with the `figure* ` environment, while long equations can be typed in the `widetext` environment.

Comment: @campa Both widetext and figure* where perfect. Please write your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `revtex` classes (both `revtex4-1` and the newer `revtex4-2` provide the `figure*` environment for two-column figures as well as the `widetext` environment for text (and equations) which should be in one column. If I remember correctly the content of the `figure*` environment always appears on the *following* page.

```
\documentclass[aps,prd,reprint]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-6]
\begin{widetext}
\[
a=b
\]
\end{widetext}
\lipsum[3-4]
\begin{figure*}
\rule{5cm}{2cm}
\caption{Text.}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum[5-6]
\end{document}
```

[image]